# Weka using gain ratio and information gain (ID3 & C4.5(J48))

Tags: weka, id3, information-theory

I am using Weka and I need to analyse a data set with information gain and gain ratio, however, I cannot find from where to set these. I understand that id3 uses information gain and J48 uses gain ratio, however, can I set the J48 to use information gain or id3 to use gain ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Launch Weka Explorer and load your `arff` file with all the attributes you want to weigh.

Then, select the tab `Select attributes` and click on the button `Choose` located under `Attribute Evaluator`.

From there, you can pick InfoGain or GainRatio as shown in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLeFN.png) (click Yes if a pop-up shows up after selecting either).